# PHP: $this->something abbreviation for easier developer notation

Tags: php, methods, naming, abbreviation

I'm writting some kind of application in PHP, where developer can write his own plugins. As for now, to each plugin constructor object `$project` is passed as argument (by reference of course). For example new plugin looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Plugins;

class newPlugin {
    private $project;
    public function __construct(\Project $project) {
        $this->project = $project;
    }

    public function Something() {
        echo $this->project->template->name();
    }

}

?>
```

I'm rewriting it, so every new plugin extends "standart" plugin. In that case, I can make a standart constructor which save passed `$project` locally as `$this->project`, and developer has less to write.
But then, every developer must remember, that there is something like $this->project...

For example:

```
<?php

namespace Plugins;

class newPlugin extends Plugin { // constructor is now in plugin class

    public function Something() {
        echo $this->project->template->name(); 
        // where should the developer know from that $this->project exists?
    }

}

?>
```

**Can I make the notation easier somehow? Abbreviate `$this->project`?** I though about making a method project() in parent that will return `$this->project`. In that case only `project()->template->name();` can be used. But this is... Simply not the best I think.

I hope everything is clear in my question, if not please ask in comment. I searched for possible answers, but found nothing.

PHP "use" is great, but only for namespaces...

BTW, there are many, many other variables under `$this->project available`, but the beginning `$this->project` is always the same. For example: `$this->project->template->name(); $this->project->router->url(); $this->project->page->title();` etc... This naming standart was imposed, so there is no way to change it.

But this is really annoying when you must write `$this->project` every time you need a simple variable from somewhere.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: save `$this->project` to local variable. `$p = $this->project; echo $p->template->name();`

Comment: You could overload __get http://php.net/__get

Comment: wouldn't `$this->project->template->name();` violate the [`law of demeter`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)?

Comment: encapsulate everything you want to be accessible in subclasses in protected methods. Optionally provide an Interface with the contractual methods.

Comment: @Yoshi yes, it would.

Comment: Thx for your replies. Localy it should be saved in each method then. And the plugin can have many methods... :(. I'm reading about overloading __get and about law of demeter right now. Thx for links! :).

Comment: By __get() overloading it may works as `$this->template->name();`

Comment: WOW! This would be great :). You can sketch an answer, and I will approve it :).

Comment: But for example: $this->project->template has only safe public methods. All other variables are private, so there is no chance to write to it. Plugin can only read it. Does this still violate this law? This is only one object deeper (all other are methods), and everything that is public is really safe. Thx for you link, very good lecture, even on wikipedia :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is sketched simple version of your project using `__get()` overloading:

```
<?php

class Template
{
  public function name()
  {
    return 'Template';
  }
}

class Project
{
  public $template;

  public function __construct(Template $template)
  {
    $this->template = $template;
  }
}

class Plugin
{
  public $project;

  public function __construct(Project $project)
  {
    $this->project = $project;
  }

  // here it is. It will be called, if $template property doesn't exist in this Plugin.
  public function __get($val)
  {
    return $this->project->$val;
  }
}

class newPlugin extends Plugin { // constructor is now in plugin class

    public function Something() {
        echo $this->template->name(); // using this we will call __get() method because $template property doesn't exist. It will be transformed to $this->project->template->name();
    }
}

$template = new Template();
$project = new Project($template);
$plugin = new newPlugin($project);

$plugin->Something();
```

Output:

```
Template
```